# Browser and mobile issues with parallax background (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've made a parallax background effect that uses the accelerometer of a mobile device (or the mouse position for desktop), but the main problem I'm running into is:

In mobile safari, and in mobile chrome, once my iphone reaches a 90+ degree angle (like this |), the parallaxed background image jumps either to the left or right (depending on the tilt of my phone) much faster than it should.

Here's the site: http://reveriesrefined.com/myftp/parBack/

Here's the relevant code:

```
function mobileCall() {
  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    $(window).on("deviceorientation", function () {
      var x = event.gamma;
      var y = event.beta;

      //data-smoothing
      if ( y > lastY + 1 || y < lastY - 1 ) {
          parallaxBackMobile(x, y);
      }
      else if ( x > lastX + 1 || x < lastX - 1 ) {
          parallaxBackMobile(x, y);
      }

      lastX = x;
      lastY = y;
    });
  }
}

function parallaxBackMobile(x, y) {
  var numX = x * 2;
  var numY = y * 2;
  var elem = $('#background');

  elem.css({
    left : -numX,
    top : -numY - 100
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

```
if ( x > 90 ) {
    x = x - (2 * (x - 90));
}
else if ( x < -90 ) {
    x = x - (2 * (x + 90));
}
```

You get the distance from the number to 90, multiply it by two, and subtract it from the original number.

This means that 0,180 becomes 0,90,0. And 0,-180 becomes 0,-90,0.